# Double border in CSS with gap in the middle?

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to somehow create a double border in CSS, with these 2 added customizations:

1. One line is slightly thicker than the other
2. There is a small gap between the two lines

**This is the kind of border I need:**

[image]

**EDIT:**

Guys, I **cannot** make any changes to my existing HTML code. I **can only** apply CSS for the existing HTML code. As far as you're concerned, consider I have a div named `sampleDiv`, and I want to apply the border on the top side of this div (see below).

Secondly, if you're using any technique other than `border`, please note that I **only** want to apply the this specialized border on the **top side** of my `sampleDiv` div.

Comment: I can't see your image, but you may need to fiddle around with background images by the sound of it. What browsers do you need to support?

Comment: check http://www.impressivewebs.com/multiple-borders-css/ and http://border-image.com/

Comment: Does the border need to go all around the element? Your image only shows one border.

Comment: I only need it on the top side. Mentioned this is the EDIT in my post now.

Comment: check out my updated answer after your last edit.

Answer (score 8):

pure CSS & Cross browser - the thickness and spacing can be customized

After your latest Edit: this is a [**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/avrahamcool/JSktg/4/)

without changing the markup, top border only.

**your HTML:**

```
<div class="sampleDiv">
    some content
</div>
```

**new CSS**

```
.sampleDiv
{
    border-top: 2px solid black;
    padding-top: 1px;
}
.sampleDiv:before
{
    content: '';
    border-top: 1px solid black;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
}
```

**If you are allowed to change the DOM:**

one line anywhere in the markup: [**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/avrahamcool/JSktg/)

**HTML:**

```
<div class="SpecialLine"></div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.SpecialLine
{
    border-top: 2px solid black;
    height: 2px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
```

full container border: [**Working  Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/avrahamcool/JSktg/2/)

**HTML:**

```
<div class="SpecialContainer">
    <div class="Content">
        here goes the content
    <div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.SpecialContainer
{
    border: 2px solid black;
    padding: 1px;
}

.Content
{
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Comment: what if he wants also a bottom border? he may want that border all over the element.

Comment: Yeah I don't think this is what he's looking for.

Comment: I don't see the problem. He can add this div wherever he want in the page + add border's all the way..

Comment: Please see the EDIT I just added to my post. Unfortunately I cannot modify the HTML. So I cannot add a second inner div like that. I can only add/subtract/edit the CSS. Also, I only need the border on the top side.

Comment: Can you reverse the position of the bars ? Like the thicker bar at the bottom ? I tried it on my own but I couldn't do this.

Answer (score 5):

There are various ways you can have multiple borders.  One way is to use `box-shadow`, you can specify multiple box shadows to create the effect you want.

**Example**

```
box-shadow: 0 0 0 5px black, 0 0 0 7px red;
```

### Update

I have created a jsFiddle to show you how you can create your borders using box-shadow

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3fu6v/2/)

Comment: I don't think this will make a double border effect, which I need ? Also, can it be modified to only show the border on the top side of a div ? See EDIT in my original post.

Comment: box-shadow is not supported in older browser. but: good answer.

Comment: Creative, but this way the "gap" will not be transparent

Answer (score 2):

There's not a specific property or something for this,but you can easily create one.Something like this:

```
html:
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="middle">put whatever you want here</div>
</div>

css:
#wrapper{
border: 3px solid black;
padding: 1px;
}

#middle{
border: 1px solid black;
}
```

here's a js fiddle link:
http://jsfiddle.net/roostaamir/GEqLJ/

UPDATE:
so I saw your edit,and here's the first thing that came to my mind(if you have the width of your `sampleDiv` this will work):

```
#sampleDiv
{
border-top: 3px solid black;
width: 500px; //this is an example
position: relative;
}

#sampleDiv:before
{
content: "";
display: block;
position: absolute;
top: 1px;
width: 500px;
height: 1px;
background-color: black;
}
```

Comment: Please see the EDIT I just added to my post. Unfortunately I cannot modify the HTML. I can only add/subtract/edit the CSS. Also, I only need the border on the top side.

Comment: The second solution here seems to do the job. It's the best of the lot. Can it be marked correct?

Answer (score 2):

Your div: `<div class="framed" />`

Simple CSS:

```
.framed {
    border: solid 2px #ccc;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 14px #ccc;
    outline: solid 8px #fff;
}
```

Demo Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/uRFsD/

Comment: Can this work without any HTML changes ? Also, can it be modified to only show the border on the top side of `framed` div, because that's what I need (see EDIT in my original post).

Comment: Great solution. Where you can use it: http://caniuse.com/#search=outline

Answer (score 0):

Not in pure CSS as far as I know. Instead you could add in a div element to your HTML, set its width to the one below it and set it's border-top, thickness, margin properties to be meet your thicker border requirement.

Comment: Yes, he provides a fiddle. I don't because I am lazy. In fact both of us are not potentially correct. If you want a border all the way around the user2078785 provides a better answer.

Comment: the image in the question was about one border. but I've updated my answer to a full container border.

Comment: Please see the EDIT I just added to my post. Unfortunately I cannot modify the HTML. So I cannot add a second inner div like that. I can only add/subtract/edit the CSS. Also, I only need the border on the top side.

Comment: @Ahmad I've updated my original answer for you as per your edit.

Comment: stop saying that this cant be done without an image, its totally wrong.

Comment: Have you read his edit? he cannot alter his HTML. Please show me how to do this in pure CSS without an image and no HTML changes.

Comment: I've read your latest update. I stand humbled and corrected. Nicely done.

Comment: I had already done so even before your last edit as we had the same idea with specifying the additional <div> and giving it a top border property.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this would be wrapping the main div in a container div for the second line like so:

```
.inner {
    border: 2px solid #000;
}

.outer {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    padding: 1px;
}
```

It's not particularly semantic but it's an easy way to get the job done.  You could also use `border-image` if being semantic is important, but it's more complicated.  I guess you could also use both `border` (inner) and `outline` (outer) on the same div, but that is not ideal since outline isn't technically part of the box model at all as far as I understand it.

Comment: Please see the EDIT I just added to my post. Unfortunately I cannot modify the HTML. So I cannot add a second inner div like that. I can only add/subtract/edit the CSS. Also, I only need the border on the top side.

Comment: If you only need it on the top side and can't alter the markup, you can accomplish the same thing using the `:before` psuedo-element mentioned in some of the other answers.

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<div></div>
<div></div>
```

CSS :

```
div{
  display: block;
  background-color: #000;
}
div:nth-child(1){
  padding: 2px 0;
}
div:nth-child(2){
  margin-top: 1px;
  padding: 1px 0;
}
```

[Check this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Fv5Uv/)

Comment: Please see the EDIT I just added to my post. Unfortunately I cannot modify the HTML. So I cannot have 2 div's side by side like that. I can only add/subtract/edit the CSS. Also, I only need the border on the top side.

Answer (score 0):

May be something like below:

```
div {
    border-top: 3px solid #00f;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 10;
    margin: 10px;
    width: 200px;
}

div:before {
    content: "";
    border-top: 1px solid #f00;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right:0;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

[**http://jsbin.com/iWiGEzU/1/edit?html,css,output**](http://jsbin.com/iWiGEzU/1/edit?html,css,output)

Answer (score 0):

Like

**[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/UERYT/)**

**css**

```
.outline {
    border-top: 2px solid #000;
    border-bottom:1px solid #000;
    height:3px;

}
```

Comment: Does this require any changes to my existing HTML code. Because I cannot change my HTML code in any way. Also, I only need the border on the top side.

Answer (score 0):

#### CSS

```
.doubleBorder
{
    border: 4px solid black;
    padding: 2px;
}

.doubleBorder>div {
    border: 2px solid black;
}
```

#### HTML

```
<div class="doubleBorder">
    <div>
        <p>Hello</p>
        <p>World</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

[**Working demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/gxXh8/)

Comment: Please see the EDIT I just added to my post. Unfortunately I cannot modify the HTML. So I cannot add a second inner div like that. I can only add/subtract/edit the CSS. Also, I only need the border on the top side.